# What is the best way to limit an owner field on a record to just a User?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

We have a requirement that we limit the ownership of an *Account* record on the form in our CRM 2013 instance to just *User* records and prevent them from even choosing a Team as the owner.

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

because it's the owner field and it's possible to set the owner in multiple points (not only inside the form, but also with "Assign" buttons on the menus) your only clean way is a a synchronous plugin that will throw an exception if the new owner is a team

Comment: You could use this approach and also add javascript at key points to hide team options which would improve user experience.

Comment: Thanks Guido, but I'm afraid the requirement was to make it so on the form, they wouldn't be able to select a Team, just a User

Answer (score 0):

The user, who has permission at user level to assign account in their security role, won't be able to put team, unless they are owners of team.

If your user is part of a business unit and they do not have permission to change it to "business unit" level, then the user will not be able to change it to a team level, since team is at BU level.